# How to connect to css correctly?

Tags: flask, pycharm, static-files

I am using flask from pycharm to create a test site. I connected my html to a css file and it made a black screen, so I created a new css file. Unfortunately, the css is connecting only with this css and I can't find out why. Is there something I did wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Register</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', 
filename='registration_style.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HaHa</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.py code :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def registration():
    return render_template('registration_activity.html')


@app.route('/test')
def hello_test():
    return 'Hola!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Make sure the css file is in a static folder and if you are using blueprints you have to specify where that static folder is and what it is called. But Flask automatically looks for a `/static` directory to look in.

Comment: @KevinHernandez I edited my post and placed a link to my project

Comment: It all looks good to me, can you post your `app.py` file

Comment: @KevinHernandez I posted it

Comment: Everything there looks good to me man.

Comment: I suppose I should close server and open it when I modify something, right? I am closing and opening the site using ctrl+c for closing and flask run for running. Is there another way?

Comment: Of course you have to do that haha

Comment: @KevinHernandez Well I did, but nothing changed...

Comment: Let me try replicating your project

Comment: @KevinHernandez ok

Answer (score 0):

I think you're **missing a css link** can you add the following to your template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='style1.css') }}">
```

so your template would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Register</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='registration_style.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='style1.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HaHa</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, it can't connect to none of the css files... I think I should take a sync project?

Comment: Remove the whitespace between your comma and filename within the url_for(...) method. That is my hunch. I would directly copy my css links I posted in my answer, restart your server, and check if that resolved the issue.

Comment: Well, I created a new css file, deleted registration_style.css and style1.css and now works. How is this possible? The code is the same, I just created a new css file?

Comment: did you restart your server? I.e did you do a python app.py? If so that’s the reason, I’d recommend you run your server in debug mode otherwise new changes aren’t picked up without a manual restart